# Message send by client and send sms to my mobile by server

Tags: .net, web-services

I want when client (without internet) send message to me (by Dot Net Program) server (with internet)  send a sms to my mobile phone.
I use web service to send sms, this service work by internet, but clients don't have internet.

(I understand a little English!!)

Comment: Q: What is your question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to send an SMS from a phone to a server, or do you want to send a message from the Server to the mobile?

Comment: when client send one message to server, I want to send message to mobile form server! ok?